# EXTJS adds the row to the top of the container on the .insert()

Tags: extjs

I am using an EXTJS `xtype: container` to create a row and when I want to insert a row into the store the row gets added to the top of the existing row instead of the bottom, is there any way to add the newly created row to the bottom?

**Below is the code:**

```
somefunc: function (token, filter, op) {
    var filter = Ext.create({
        xtype: 'container',
        height: 30,
        cls: 'purge-filter-item',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'middle'
        },
        items: [
            this.typeCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                emptyText: $L('Select a filter...'),
                store: this.menuStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                    fields: ['key', 'title'],
                    data: this.getFilterValues()
                })
            })
        ]
    });
    this.insert(0, filter);

    this.doLayout();
    return filter;
}
```

Any idea why this could be happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why this could be happening and how to fix this?

Because you are using [`insert()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-insert) method instead of this you can use [`add()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-add) method it will by default add in last index.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g6u)**, I have created a demo using `add()` method to adding new component. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

## CODE SNIPPET

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {

            title: 'Add new row',

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            tbar: [{
                text: 'Add new',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    var panel = btn.up('panel');
                    panel.add({
                        xtype: 'container',
                        height: 30,
                        cls: 'purge-filter-item',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'hbox',
                            align: 'middle'
                        },
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            emptyText:'enter value here',
                            fieldLabel:'this is field '+( panel.items.items.length+1)
                        }]
                    });
                }
            }]

        })
    }
});
```